# Flot: zooming on dynamic graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I'm having an issue where when I try to zoom in on a certain area of my graph that is continuously updating the plotselected event fires off numerous times instead of just once. I've slowed down the update rate in the attached jsfiddle significantly so that you aren't overwhelmed with alert messages to show the multiple plotselected events fired off. With a quicker refresh rate you could be stuck with 50+ of those messages. Anyways, is there a way to only fire off that event handler for the last event in the chain that's created after selecting the area? Suspect code in question (this works fine in static mode):

```
$("#overview").on("plotselected",  function (event, ranges) {
    alert(ranges.xaxis.from+','+ranges.xaxis.to);
    plot.setSelection({
        xaxis: {from:ranges.xaxis.from,to:ranges.xaxis.to}
    });
});
```

full jsfiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/grkblood13/6TG5a/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are attaching the `plotselected` event handler to your plot div every time you call `plotData`.  These are cumulative!

So, simply remove the `$("#overview").on("plotselected"` call outside that function.

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6TG5a/1/).

Comment: this is probably a different issue but if I copy and paste your updated code into the original jsfiddle and then rerun it doesn't work but if I fork it instead then run it works fine. you don't know what might be causing that do you?

Comment: @Brad.Smith, I tried cutting and pasting the updated fiddle into the original and then re-ran, I had no problems.  Are you sure jsFiddle actually re-ran it?  Sometimes it can act a little wonky.